# Calculate number of zeros of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to calculate number of zeros of following polynomial :
$W(z)=z^7+6z^4+1$ on right half-plane. I will be very glad if someone checked if it's correct.
Lets take half cirle with diameter R i.e $\{Re^{i t}: t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\}$
On a half circle $z^7$ dominates so argument changes by $7\pi$.
Now for imaginary axis: 
$$w(iy)=-iy^7+6y^4+1$$
$$u(y)=6y^4+1$$
$$v(y)=-y^7$$
I draw a sketch how I think it will look like : 
[image]

With $R$ and $-R$ bigger we get closer to imaginary axis. So change in argument is: $\Delta arg= arg(-R)-arg(R)=\pi/2-(-\pi/2)=\pi$
So the total change in argument is $8\pi$ So using argument principle we get 4 zeros in right half-plane. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture looks good -- I would just like to stress the fact that the dashed line (representing the image of the half-circle in the $w$-plane) winds up around the origin $7$ times.

It may wind around in very large curves that are much too far away from to be shown in the drawing, but in between its two endpoints -- $W(iR)$ and $W(-iR)$ --, it will complete $7$ full turns and a bit more (but not enough for an eigth turn) around the origin.
The solid black line you drew $($the image of the 'almost' imaginary axis $[-iR,R])$ should be the final segment that completes the eigth loop.